# Global ESLint overrides project ESLint

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

I have my default ESLint style used in all my projects (it has been set up globally in VS Code preferences file / settings.json), but there are some other projects that have its specific lint configuration (.eslintrc file under the project folder).

However, when coding for that specific project, the lint used is still the global one.

How to override the global ESLint with the project one for all projects?
So that anytime I have a new project with its own ESLint config, there is no need to re-config the global ESLint for my default projects.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `”root”: true,` to your `.eslintrc` file.